# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException this erro appear in spring boot web

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

this is first time user spring boot an ihave this error please any one help me to solve this error i am using springv tool suite

> ```
> this is the pom.xml
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.zatr</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> and this is WebAppApplication.java

```
package com.zatr.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication

public class WebAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebAppApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

> ```
>  and this is HomeController.java
> ```

```
     package com.zatr.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping("home")
public void home() {
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
}
```

> and this is my error appear when run the code

```
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:456) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:105) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:178) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.zatr.demo.WebAppApplication.main(WebAppApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:181) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5060) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2019-07-26 20:26:19.608 ERROR 1868 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:456) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:105) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:178) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.zatr.demo.WebAppApplication.main(WebAppApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:181) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5060) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2019-07-26 20:26:19.609  INFO 1868 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-07-26 20:26:19.616  WARN 1868 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2019-07-26 20:26:19.628  INFO 1868 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-26 20:26:19.636 ERROR 1868 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/Mohamed%20Ramadan/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

this is first time user spring boot an ihave this error please any one help me to solve this error i am using springv tool suite

Comment: the error description at the end of the console output should point you towards the issue. It looks like there is something wrong with the classpath of the project. Did you import the project using the `Maven -> Import As Existing Maven Project` wizard, so that the Maven integration of STS/Eclipse takes care of the classpath libs? And how did you configure your JDK that you use to run the project? Maybe there is the servlet-api JAR added manually to the JDK classpath, so that it appears on every launch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify 8+ tomcat version in your POM

```
<properties>
<tomcat.version>8.0.30</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: i added this line in pom.xml  but this error is appear **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception;*
**

Comment: if you need the validator add:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: otherwise exclude it inside your starter web dependency